# CRUD Operations for list of entities in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm wondering what is the best way to implement CRUD operations in React Redux in case of **List of entities**.

Requirements:
1. Every row contain an entity
2. Changing a value in a text input trigger a PUT call to BE
3. Every row has Delete operation trigger a DELETE call to BE
4. Form has an ADD action trigger a POST call to BE

Notes:
1. No single Submit button

I thought about [Redux Form](http://redux-form.com) for that but since I don't have a single submit operation I find it less appropriate (Feel free to correct me)

[image]

Comment: You have an option that you can save the form on blur event of your input fields, but this is a good option when you have only one input field. But here you have two input fields so you should definately have a submit button. Or if you still want to go with out submit, then you have to save the form on first blur and then after you have to send update request for the saved item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redux Form for that. If you setup a validator for the form, you can define if a field is dependent on another. Redux Form will run this validator for each change in any field.

You can setup something like Redux Observable or Redux Thunk to submit the form on Redux Form's `CHANGE` action when there are no validation errors in the form.

This way, you will submit the form on change, only if all the related fields are also filled.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't want to submit all the entities on change, only the relevant entity, for example submit only a deleted entity.
Say this list is my users list - I dont want to update All my users when a change was made in a specific user.

Comment: You don't have to submit everything. Each `CHANGE` action has the field which was changed, you will only submit this, and any other related, field.

Comment: Thanks @squgeim, I'm starting to understand - So you actually say - do not use the submit of the form just use the actions?

Comment: Yup. That way you can customize the request as required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Redux. This is how I would do it. I will keep a state in the reducer which is called "personList". I will put all components in a container and map the personList to a property of the container called "propPersonList". When I create the ListItemComponent, I would also pass the index of the person in the list to the component as a property "propIndex". The onChange handler of the two inputs will dispatch an action with payload {index: this.props.propIndex, value: event.target.value}, then trigger a PUT request to backend (use lodash module to throttle it instead of triggering it everytime the input changes). The reducer will take care of the actions and update the state according to the payload. The add button will dispatch another action and the reducer will simply add an empty entity to the state, then trigger a request to the backend. The remove button will dispatch an action with the index as the payload, and the reducer will remove the corresponding entity from the list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - Would you use Redux form in your suggestion? if so how do you handle the Submit regarding the different CRUD scenarios?

Comment: I don't think Redux form is necessary. Basically, all the requests are done through asynchronous calls, and you dispatch an action to update the state when you get a response from your request(if necessary).